# Efficient data structure to look up co-occurrence within a document

Tags: data-structures, data-mining

I have 10 million documents. Each document is a set of tokens (about 100 unique tokens) regardless of their frequency (bag-of-words). All unique tokens in all documents form the vocabulary `V`. The size of `V` is roughly 50000.

**Requirement 1**:

Given a set of tokens, say `(t1, t2)` (there may be more than two tokens in practice) where `t1,t2 in V`, I want to find all tokens that co-occur with `t1,t2` in at least one document. That is to say, find all tokens `u`, satisfying `u in V` and `t1,t2,u` **constituting a subset of at least one document**.

**Requirement 2**:

Given a set of tokens, **find documents that contain these tokens**.

Is there any **efficient** data structure to fulfill my requirements? "*Efficienct*" means avoid iterating all documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (usually implemented as either a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)) that maps each token to the set of documents that contain this token.

When given two tokens t1,t2, compute the intersection of the two corresponding sets of documents. This gives you the set of documents that contain both t1 and t2. Then return the union of all the tokens contained in these documents.

In python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def build_map(documents):
    m = defaultdict(set)
    for i, document in enumerate(documents):
        for token in document:
            m[token].add(i)
    return m

def cooccuring_with_pair(m, documents, t1, t2):
    doc_ids = set.intersection(m[t1], m[t2])
    return set().union(*(documents[i] for i in doc_ids))
```

Testing the python code with a small example:

```py
documents = [set(s.split()) for s in ('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'the grey cat jumps in fright when hearing the dog', 'two brown mice are chased by a dog', 'the quick brown fox grows old and slow')]

m = build_map(documents)
print(m)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'brown': {0, 2, 3}, 'lazy': {0}, 'fox': {0, 3}, 'the': {0, 1, 3}, 'over': {0}, 'jumps': {0, 1}, 'dog': {0, 1, 2}, 'quick': {0, 3}, 'cat': {1}, 'hearing': {1}, 'fright': {1}, 'grey': {1}, 'when': {1}, 'in': {1}, 'mice': {2}, 'by': {2}, 'a': {2}, 'chased': {2}, 'two': {2}, 'are': {2}, 'and': {3}, 'slow': {3}, 'grows': {3}, 'old': {3}})

for t1, t2 in [('jumps', 'dog'), ('brown', 'fox'), ('cat', 'fox')]:
    print(t1, t2)
    print(cooccuring_with_pair(m, documents, t1, t2))
    print()
# jumps dog
# {'brown', 'lazy', 'fox', 'cat', 'the', 'hearing', 'over', 'jumps', 'dog', 'fright', 'grey', 'when', 'quick', 'in'}
#
# brown fox
# {'brown', 'lazy', 'and', 'fox', 'the', 'slow', 'grows', 'old', 'over', 'jumps', 'dog', 'quick'}
#
# cat fox
# set()
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way? I think merging big sets is still not very efficient given a large number of documents.

Comment: How big are the sets? Given a token, how many documents contain that token?

Comment: Note we're not merging the big sets, we're intersecting them

Comment: I just tried intersecting two sets of size 1 million in python with an intersection of size 500,000, and it was pretty fast

Comment: Yes, intersecting. Since there are 50000 unique tokens and 10 M documents with each one having 100 unique tokens, I think, on average, a token may be linked to a  set of size 20000. Let me have a try.